# Doctrine returning join query in different arrays

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
$query
    ->select('s', 'p')
    ->innerJoin(
        'test\Entity\ProductQuantity',
        's',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'p.sku = s.sku'
    )
    ->orderBy('p.productId', 'DESC');

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This query must return result of 2 tables, what I get:

```
result = array(
[0] => 'table1',
[1]=> 'table2',
[2] => 'table1',
[3]=> 'table2',
)
```

Why I'm get 2 tables in 2 arrays ? this is join query and it must be in 1 array, how to merge result of join query in 1 array and get:

```
result = array(
[0] => 'table1table2',
[1] => 'table1table2',
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution in add to select needed fields and then result is 1 array

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $query
        ->select('p.sku', 's.quantity', 'p.priceAmount')
        ->innerJoin(
            'LeosEbayGateway\Entity\ProductQuantity',
            's',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            'p.sku = s.sku'
        )
        ->orderBy('p.productId', 'DESC');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Result:

```
result = array(
[0] => 'table1table2',
[1] => 'table1table2',
)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get result as a an array by using :

```
$query->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it! Replace ``getResult()`` by ``getScalarResult()``. Thanks.