# Why Doctrine iterate return different data structure for first and next steps?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Get some data form DB using doctrine Query iterate

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('u as user', 'i as info', 'COUNT(p.id) as count_product')
        ->from(User::class, 'u')
        ->leftJoin(UserProfile::class, 'i', Join::WITH, 'u.id=i.userId')
        ->leftJoin(Products::class, 'p', Join::WITH, 'u.id=p.userId')
        ->groupBy('u.id')
        ->getQuery();

$iterableResult = $query->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $data) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

result for first step will be

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {'user' => userObject}
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'info' =>
    NULL
    'count_product' =>
    string(2) "12"
  }

}
```

And for next data

```
array(3) {
[0] =>
  array(1) {'user' => userObject}
[1] =>
  array(1) {
    'info' =>
    NULL
  }
[3] =>
 array(1) {
    'count_product' =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Why doctrine/orm returns data in different structure for one query?

Comment: Does it happen when you do ``$iterableResult = $query->getQuery()->getResult();`` instead of ``$iterableResult = $query->iterate();``?

Comment: getResult show all data as first step of iterate. but like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342934/doctrine-returning-join-query-in-different-arrays).
In query allowed only one object? for other cases i should use getScalarResult ?